# Dynamically resize iBooks HTML widget

Tags: html, ibooks, ibook-author

I want to create a dynamic widget for iBooks 2, but I can not dynamically resize the widget to match portrait or landscape mode. I found Apples documentation for [resizing dashboard widgets](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/Resizing.html) but this doesn't seem to work within iBooks.
As an alternative it would help, if I can lock the orientation for the widget.
Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget object that is instantiated in dashboard and iBook contexts. It is not clear, however, if it contains any information about orientation.

It may be possible to add a listener for widget.didEnterWidgetMode, as demonstrated in this [widget events demo project on github](https://github.com/miguel/iBooks-Author-widget-events/blob/master/we.wdgt/main.html), and then read your window dimensions. This should tell you whether you are in portrait or landscape.